# How to send a memory command to memory controller

Tags: memory, memory-management, linux-device-driver

According to the DDR3 document [1], the memory module has multiple modes, which is defined by the memory controller's Mode Register. The mode register, such as MR0, can be set by the `Mode Register Set (MRS)` command.

**My question is:**

How should I send the `MRS` command (in Linux) in order to change the memory mode?

It does not seem to be a CPU instruction that I can just use in assembly.

[1] https://www.micron.com/~/media/documents/products/data-sheet/dram/ddr3/2gb_ddr3_sdram.pdf

Comment: The memory controller is a system peripheral device.  Its registers could be I/O or memory mapped.  Consult the board or SoC documentation for its register addresses.  FWIW for ARM the memory controller is expected to be completely initialized prior to the start of the Linux kernel; i.e. the boot program is expected to perform the initialization.

Comment: @sawdust is absolutely correct. When Linux kernel loads, the memory is already initialised. It's the bootloader who does that.

Comment: @sawdust Thank you so much for your answer! If its registers are MMIO, Linux or firmware should initialize it. If it's initialize before Linux, I guess it's in U-boot for ARM? But how about x86 machine? Would you mind providing some keywords that I can search? I searched in Linux source code and online for the ddr driver, but I didn't find where the MRS or PRECHARGE command were called... :-(

Comment: For x86 I assume that the memory initialization is performed by the BIOS or UEFI.  The Linux kernel has to execute out of main memory (i.e. RAM).  That RAM (i.e. its memory controller) has to be initialized *before* the RAM can even be accessed (e.g. code loaded into it) and have code execute from it.  Therefore memory-controller code in kernel source would probably only be for sleep or low-power modes.  Only some arches use U-Boot for memory initialization, i.e. those that use the SPL feature.

Comment: Take a look at the **mem_ctl_info** structure  in **include/linux/edac.h**